# Application Data Path Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have created a Python program which works great on windows, but now I have brought it over to my Apple Mac to test it out. The application has a sqlite database and I also have a couple of error logging files which are being kept in when the application is installed or simply initialised from the source code.

On the windows platform, to define the the database path I used the following command:

```
appDataPath = os.environ["APPDATA"] + "\\FOLDERNAME\\"
```

But on my mac, I am getting the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from view import tick
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/APPNAME/view/tick.py", line 8, in <module>
    from controller import get
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/APPNAME/controller/get.py", line 4, in <module>
    appDataPath = os.environ["/Users/myname/Desktop"] + "\\FOLDERNAME\\"
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: '/Users/myname/Desktop'
```

What can I do to make this work? I tried changing this to my desktop location but still no joy. Where does a mac store the applications data? On Windows as you may very well know, is in the Roaming directory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're attempting to look up the literal string `/Users/myname/Desktop` in `os.environ`.  That isn't the name of an environment var.  Also, your slashes are backwards (`\\Foldername\\ `).  Use `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.environ` is a dictionary containing environment variables. There is no variable called `/Users/myname/Desktop`. That's why you're getting a `KeyError`. But there **is** a variable called `HOME`.

```
>>> os.environ['HOME']
'/Users/NAME/'
```

That should work equally on windows and OSX.

Now, if you want to concatenate paths, you should use `os.path.join`:

```
>>> os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'MYPROJECT')
'/Users/NAME/MYPROJECT'
```